# Writing lines from input file to output file based on the order in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have an input data `input.dat` that looks like this:

```
0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00
-0.28   1.39
-0.49   1.24
-0.57   1.65
-0.61   2.11
-0.90   1.73
-0.87   2.29
```

I have have a list denoting line numbers as follows:

```
linenum = [7, 2, 6]
```

I need to write to a file `output_veloc_max.dat` the rows in `input.dat` that correspond to `linenum` values in the same order.

The result should look like this:

```
-0.61 2.11
0.00 0.00 
-0.57 1.65
```

I have written the following code:

```
linenum=[7,2,6]
i=1

with open('inputv.dat', 'r') as f5, open('output_veloc_max.dat', 'w') as out:
    for line1 in f5:
        if i in linenum:
            print(line1,  end=' ', file=out)
            print(i,line1)
        i+=1
```

But, it gives me output that looks like this:

```
2 0.00  0.00
6 -0.57 1.65
7 -0.61 2.11
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Other than storing each line as you come across it and printing at the end?

Comment: I want that 7th row first is printed and then 2nd and at the end 6th row!

Comment: ... Then do so?

Comment: but the loop begins with 2 and writes first the 2nd line. You should imagine, there are more than 100000 numbers of row and it must be automatically!

Comment: Have you tried storing it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Store the values as you encounter them in a dictionary `d` with the keys denoting the line number and the value holding the line contents. Write them to the file with `writelines` according to the order of `linenum`. Use `enumerate(fileobj, 1)` to get a line number for each line instead of an explicit counter like `i`:

```
linenum=[7,2,6]
d = {}

with open('inputv.dat', 'r') as f5, open('output_veloc_max.dat', 'w') as out:
    for num, line1 in enumerate(f5, 1):
        if num in linenum:
            d[num] = line1
    out.writelines([d[i] for i in linenum])
```

Of course, you can further trim this down with a dictionary comprehension:

```
linenum = [7, 2, 6]
with open('inputv.dat', 'r') as f5, open('output_veloc_max.dat', 'w') as out:
    d = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(f5, 1) if k in linenum}
    out.writelines([d[i] for i in linenum])
```